# Ionic push with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am working on an ionic app in sublime. is there a way to add firebase fcm with android studio?

The file stucture in sublime is different from android studio. All the firebase tutorial I have seen reference two different gradle files(project/application) in android studio as well as a sync command. How can I translate that to my ionic project in sublime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for an ionic project, you will need to add the cordova plugin for firebase, try using this one [here](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/), the plugin documentation has detail of how to add the plugin , you can also check out this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvrcmOCVKY8)